# How to write $\delta(f(x,y))$ in terms of $\delta$ function?

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I know that $\delta(f(x))=\sum_i\frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{f'(x_i)}$. What will be the expression if $f$ is a function of two variables, i.e. $\delta(f(x,y))$?

Comment: There is a similar formula. You replace the $f'(x_i)$'s with Jacobian determinants.

Comment: Kindly mention explicitly which Jacobian you are referring to and what will be in the numerator. If you kindly give me a reference for the proof, it will be helpful. @KennyWong

Comment: Therefore, what is the final formula ? Besides, a very thorough and well written approach to these questions can be found [here](https://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/wheeler/documents/Miscellaneous%20Math/Delta%20Functions/Simplified%20Dirac%20Delta.pdf)